# What is define([ , function ]) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, requirejs-define

I see this being used all the time in JavaScript:

```
define(['param1', 'param2'], function() {

});
```

What is the `define` function?

Comment: Look up [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) and the [AMD API](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD).

Comment: I would refer anyone who wants to learn more about this, AMD or different modules in JS I'd refer you to an excellent article written not by me on Medium 
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-modules-a-beginner-s-guide-783f7d7a5fcc

Answer (score 92, accepted):

define() is part of the AMD spec of js

See:

- https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD

Edit: Also see @Claudio Redi's answer. Likely the more relevant explanation.

Answer (score 131):

That's probably a [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/) module definition

Check [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define) for more details

> RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader. It is optimized for in-browser use, but it can be used in other JavaScript environments, like Rhino and Node. Using a modular script loader like RequireJS will improve the speed and quality of your code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10331369/1549918 for a good explanation of `define`, it's purpose and the function definition