# How to load the highcharts plugins?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to use this 2 Highcharts plugins:

`<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://highslide-software.github.io/export-csv/export-csv.js"></script>`

The thing is that in my code I cannot call them from the HTML. I am using javascript `define()` instead:

I copied the content of the scripts into local files and I am calling them this way:

`define(['jquery', 'jquery.spectrum', '../lib/highcharts.js', '../lib/highcharts-exporting.js', '../lib/highcharts-export-csv.js'], function($) {`

But it is giving me an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined` in the line 23 (last line) of `highcharts-exporting.js`.

However, if I remove `'../lib/highcharts-export-csv.js'` it works fine. So, I am able to use the exporting.js file but not the export-csv.js one.

Comment: Have you renamed the file? `export-csv.js` => `highcharts-export-csv.js`

Comment: I think this question might be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331305/what-is-define-used-for-in-javascript-aside-from-the-obvious

Comment: @hagope Yes, the file is being found

Comment: @hagope Are you suggesting that export-csv could not be usable from the `define`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround:

I just pasted the contente of `highcharts-exporting.js` and `highcharts-export-csv.js` below  the content of `highcharts.js`.

Consequently my `define` line is just:

`define(['jquery', 'jquery.spectrum', '../lib/highcharts.js'], function($) {`

Comment: If somebody come up with a better solution I'll be more than happy to change the accepted answer (if that is possible).